# Public constructor for nested class

Tags: java, android

I'm parsing a JSON and bumped into an exception saying I don't have default constructor for one of my entities. Here is the code:

```
public class MyPromosResponse extends BaseResponse {

    public MyPromosResponseData response;

    public MyPromosResponse() {
    }

    public TreeSet<Promo> getMyPromosResponseData() {
        return new TreeSet<Promo>(response.getEvents());
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    class MyPromosResponseData {
        public ArrayList<Promo> events;
        public ArrayList<Table1PromoData> Table1;

        public MyPromosResponseData() {
        }

        public ArrayList<Promo> getEvents() {
            return events;
        }

        ArrayList<Table1PromoData> getTable1() {
            return Table1;
        }

    }

    class Table1PromoData {
        public int id;
        public int eventid;
        public int cardholderid;

        public Table1PromoData() { // Here is the constructor.
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getEventid() {
            return eventid;
        }

        public void setEventid(int eventid) {
            this.eventid = eventid;
        }

        public int getCardholderid() {
            return cardholderid;
        }

        public void setCardholderid(int cardholderid) {
            this.cardholderid = cardholderid;
        }
    }

}
```

When I have `Table1PromoData` as a nested class I have the error the default constructor can't be found, but there is a public constructor defined. If I move it to a separate file everything is fine - the lib finds the constructor.

Why the default constructor become visible after I moved it to a separate file?

Comment: Make your nested class `static`.

Comment: @Sotirios, thank you, it works after I set it as static.

Comment: @silk You're welcome, check out Zim-Zam's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into problems with JSON serializers (specifically Jackson) if my inner classes aren't static - apparently if your inner class isn't static then the default constructor gets mucked up

Answer (score 9):

Because inner classes can also be public, private, or protected.  If you don't specify, its private and can't be seen outside the class.  You need to declare the class as public.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable but this didn't help until after I set it as `static`.